# Can I randomize answers to a message box in AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm programming a game where I need, at one point, the ability to randomize the answer to a message box. What I mean is if Yes is clicked, there's a 50% chance that it is the correct answer, and the same goes for clicking No.

Something like this:

```
msgBox, 308, Spin!, Try your luck.
   ifMsgBox Yes // replace Yes with function that randomly outputs yes or no here
      {
         msgBox, You're lucky!
      }
      else
      {
         msgBox, Sorry, try again.
      }
```

I'm a beginner with AHK—basically, what I need is the ability to pass either Yes or No to the ifMsgBox function. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MsgBox, 308, Spin!, Try your luck.

ifMsgBox % myRandomFunction(answer)
  MsgBox Lucky
else
  MsgBox Not Lucky

myRandomFunction(answer)
{
  Random answer, 0, 1
  return answer == 1 ? "Yes" : "No"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need *ifMsgBox* because you're ignoring the user's answer.

```
MsgBox 308, Spin!, Try your luck
Random random_num, 0, 1
MsgBox % random_num == 1 ? "You're lucky!" : "Sorry you lost"
```

Comment: I think I prefer your previous answer as I plan on continuing with more message boxes after.